# keyboard problem ubuntu LTS 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I installed Ubuntu LTS 18.04 just now , and added my language to the keyboard but it is still typing as English.
I had this issue after reboot.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: By "English" do you mean Qwerty ?

Comment: i could added persian (my lang) when i want type its typing eng , dont know why

Comment: Under Settings > Language and Region what do you have Input Resources set to?

Comment: @Graham what do you mean about resources?
in addition i have to tell in language support i installed my language but still typing eng

Comment: Its an option under Settings > Language and Region and on that screen there is a section entitled Input Resources.